# How do I create a uninstantiated array of images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a way to store a set of images in my MATLAB function. Is there a way to set aside space for n images ahead of time and initialize them later?

I tried doing something like this:

```
array_of_images = zeros(1,5); % array of 5 images
```

but when I try to initialize:

```
array_of_images(1,1) = imread('image_01.jpg');
```

MATLAB reports `Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts`, so I am looking for a way to do something equivalent.

Comment: You should do array_of_images=zeros(nRows,nCols,5) if these are grayscale images. `nRows` and `nCols` are image height and width respectively. Alternative is to use `cell array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the output of  `imread('image_01.jpg')`, this propably something like 1200x800x3.

Then you have to preallocate `ar=zeros(1200,800,3,5)` and assign with `ar(:,:,:,index)=imread('image.jpg')`